# Using Max with multiple columns from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max

I have 3 tables t1=items (items) t2=sales offer catalogue dates
t3=sales offer catalogue item offer price (same item can be included multiple times)

t1

| t1id | t1itemcode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 |
| 2 | A002 |
| 3 | A003 |
| 4 | A004 |
| 5 | A005 |

t2

| t2id | t2endofferdate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-25 |
| 2 | 2021-03-28 |
| 3 | 2021-02-10 |
| 4 | 2021-04-10 |

t3

| t3id | t3.t1id | t3.t2id | t3.formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1--- | 1------ | 4------ | 10,80----- |
| 2--- | 2------ | 2------ | 22,00----- |
| 3--- | 2------ | 3------ | 13,00----- |
| 4--- | 5------ | 2------ | 10,00----- |
| 5--- | 2------ | 4------ | 11,25----- |
| 6--- | 1------ | 3------ | 4,50------ |

I initially needed the itemid and the max(enddate).
I created the following SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, max(t2.ENDDATE) ENDDATE
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.t1id 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t3.t2id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

This works fine and the output is OK. Item id not repeated multiple times and in the 2nd col the max date that appears combined with the item from t2 (item) and (t3).

```
ID           ENDDATE
1      -- 2021-04-10 
2      -- 2021-04-10 
5      -- 2021-03-28 
3      -- NULL
4      -- NULL
```

Now I have to add a col with the formula from t3. I believe that a subquery is needed, but I'm struggling with the syntax. Actually, I need the formula for the certain join of the item (t1) id with the enddate.

The result has to be like this:

```
ID           ENDDATE      FORMULA
1      -- 2021-04-10        10,80
2      -- 2021-04-10        11,25
5      -- 2021-03-28        10,00
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `Actually, I need the formula for the certain join of the item (t1) id with the enddate` what does that mean?

Comment: For this to work, you need to specify the grain of the result - if you want each row in the result to represent the ID in t1. If so, for table t3, you need to specify how to select a formula when there are multiple formulas for a t1 id (e.g. for the t1id value of 2). Do you use min or max? Once you specify the grain, the solution is pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign a row number based on the `ENDDATE` and then only take the first row per `ID` you can pull multiple column values.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.ID, t2.ENDDATE, t3.FORMULA
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.ENDDATE DESC) RN
    FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.t1id 
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t3.t2id = t2.id
)
SELECT ID, ENDDATE, FORMULA
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that it works.
As an alternative we thought this :

Comment: I tested it in a demo database and it worked.
Now I have to test it in the real one :)